# Invalid Active Record Statement Rails 2.3.16

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am using Rails 2.3.16, Ruby 1.8.7

For the following line of code I ma getting error as follows:

**Code:**

```
ForeignScheduledItem.find(:all, 
                          :conditions => { :foreign_scheduled_item => 
                                           { :scheduled_items => { :subscription_id => params[:subscription_id] } } }, 
                          :joins => :scheduled_item).each { |i| @subscriptions.push(Subscription.find_by_id(i.subscription_id)) }
```

**Error:**

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid):
  app/controllers/api/cache_controller.rb:47:in `expire_day_event_sets'
  config/initializers/restfulx.rb:18:in `call'
  config/initializers/restfulx.rb:38:in `call'
  /home/ranjit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
  /home/ranjit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
  /home/ranjit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
  /home/ranjit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
  /home/ranjit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
  /home/ranjit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
  /home/ranjit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
  /home/ranjit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
  /home/ranjit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
  /home/ranjit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
```

Can u please help in this regard.

Comment: Full error message is required to solve your problem.

Comment: I was not aware of inside `:conditions`, I can put such a nested hash. Cool.

Comment: @Arup Rakshit - this is Rails 2. If you are not using Rails 2 don't use :conditions hash, AR has better syntax for that.

Comment: @Octopus-Paul I am learning Rails in version 4.1.1

Comment: @Marek Lipka . I have updated error message

Comment: On a totally unrelated note, if this is possible, you should update your rails version to at least Rails 3 ASAP or you will face serious security issues.

Comment: @Intrepidd Security issues. How come ?Can u explain in brief ?

Comment: @Ranzit Rails 2 has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. This means that if a critical bug or security flaw is found, they will no bother looking for a fix on the 2.x branch. Also, most gems will drop compatibility for rails 2.